# 4 columns at 1280px, 3rd column below 2nd at 1024px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have just started out with bootstrap and cannot work out how make a column appear underneath another column for medium devices.

large devices

```
[A] [B] [C] [D]
```

medium devices

```
[A] [B] [D]
    [C]
```

Small devices

```
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
```

Ideally I would like column C appearing under B for medium devices, but cannot see a way of doing this.  All columns should have equal widths.  Confused

Hey sorry, just starting out and reading the docs.  I have tried putting column B and C within a 6 column div, but at full size it does not show the columns with equal width and doesnt show c under b.  Heres my current layout.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">Column A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">Column B</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">Column C</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">Column D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You forgot to include what you've tried and why it isn't working or what is confusing you. In its current state, your question is a request for code.

Comment: i have added what i have tried so far, sorry i have only just started learning bootstrap.

Comment: It would seem you need to keep reading the documentation, because that's not how the grid system works. Check out [their examples](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and play with them in an online IDE like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [Bootply](http://bootply.com).

Comment: To do it on exactly at 1024px you would need to create custom css. As @CarrieKendall referenced below the closest breakpoints are 992px or 1200px.

Comment: So you will have to read up more on Bootstrap.  It is too bad that there are people here that are down vote happy.  Your question is legit and you are just looking for some helpful direction.  Take a look at my correct, yet -4 down voted answer and it will get you on the right track.  It will give you what you want and you'll just need to modify the BS breakpoints to meet your specific width requirements.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Its pretty easy.  With Bootstrap 3 you build from smallest to largest.  So the default should be your third case already.  I cant recall what the default `xs` breakpoint is for width but if under 500 you still are not getting the single column just add the class `.col-sm-12` A-D.

Then add `.col-md-4` to get your medium case.  You may have to add `.col-md-offset-4`to `[D]` to get the positioning you want.

And finally give each A-D the class `.col-lg-3`

That should do it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">Column A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">Column B</div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">Column C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Column D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no need to pull from memory, the breakpoints are in the [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: I downvoted because your example [doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lcx5d1y/) and your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Way to down vote without adding anything helpful to the answer or discussion.

Comment: I actually did add to the discussion by telling you why I downvoted. [This is how content is graded on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down). Many people wont (and don't have to) give a reason for why they downvoted. I'm happy to remove the downvote when your answer makes sense and is accurate :)